# Using Euler Phi function to show that there are infinitely many primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know Euclid's clever way of proving that there are infinitely many primes but while I was studying, I also saw a sentence on the book: "Euler-phi function can also be used to show that there are infinitely many primes." but could not figure out how. Could you please help me to understand it?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that there are only a finite number of primes say $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$. Look at the product of these finite primes i.e. $$m = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$$
Now consider any number $n > 1$. Since there are only finite primes, one of the $p_j$'s must divide $n$. Hence, $\gcd(m,n) > 1$. Hence, $\phi(m) = 1$.

Can you now finish it off?

Comment: I guess it must go on like this: we know that $\phi(m) = 1$ however according to the multiplicative property of the phi function, $\phi(m) = (p_1-1)*(p_2-1)*...*(p_k-1)$ which is not clearly equal to 1. However I could not exactly understand why $\phi(m) = 1$. Maybe I should give it some time. = )

Comment: I guess I understood why $\phi(m) = 1$. Any selection of (m,n) will not be relatively prime only (m,1) will be relatively prime hence $\phi(m) = 1$. That is brilliant. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Zxy Precisely. $\phi(m) = \#\{n \leq m: \gcd(m,n) = 1\}$

Comment: @Zyx $\rm\:m \ge 2\:\Rightarrow\:1\ne m\!-\!1\:$ are both coprime to $\rm\:m\:$ so $\rm\:\phi(m)\ge 2.\:$ This is just the $\rm\:m\!-\!1\:$ (vs. $\rm\:m\!+\!1)\:$ form of Euclid's proof.